# Notepad++ regex find digits

Tags: notepad++, regex

I have a text file as follows:

```
/XXX/10000/XXX-15/10000 /XXX/10000/XXX-15/10000
/XXX/10000/XXX-17/10001 /XXX/10000/XXX-17/10001
/XXX/10000/XXX-18/10002 /XXX/10000/XXX-18/10002
/XXX/10000/XXX-272/10004 /XXX/10000/XXX-272/10004
/XXX/10000/XXX-322/10008 /XXX/10000/XXX-322/10008
```

I have task to get rid from files after the XXX-? folder so the output will be look like

```
 /XXX/10000/XXX-15 /XXX/10000/XXX-15
/XXX/10000/XXX-17 /XXX/10000/XXX-17
/XXX/10000/XXX-18 /XXX/10000/XXX-18
/XXX/10000/XXX-272 /XXX/10000/XXX-272
/XXX/10000/XXX-322 /XXX/10000/XXX-322
```

I try to find using the regex [^A-Z]/[^A-Z][0-9]*, but it returns the first digit before the `/`, like 5/10000, 7/10001, 8/10002 and so on, but I need to find and remove only /10000.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `XXX-\d+\K/\S+`
- Replace with: `LEAV EMPTY`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
XXX-        # literally XXX-
\d+         # 1 or more digits
\K          # forget all we have seen until this position
/           # a slash
\S+         # 1 or more non spaces
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]